# SSRS2008R2 : how we can use two 'Interval" is a line chart X-axis label?

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I am new in ssrs world. I just want to use two interval in a single Horizontal Axis label. e.g. I am using the Date field (sample_date) in X axis, For January the interval will be 31 and February interval will be 28 and Dec interval will be 31 etc. The interval type is Day. 
can anyone help me regarding that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure if I believe I understand your question is you wish to show Month End dates instead of day dates.  You need to do a few things to do that:

1. You need to see how many days you have in a month from you dataset.  Here is an example dataset:

   ```
   declare @Dates table ( dt date, val int)

   insert into @Dates values('1-1-12', 10),('1-10-12',20),('1-30-12',14),('2-1-12', 11),('2-11-12', 19),('2-20-12', 20),('3-10-12',10)

   select *,  datediff(day,
   Dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, dt), 0),
   Dateadd(day, -1, Dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, dt) + 1, 0))
   ) as DaysInMonth
   from @Dates
   ```
2. You now have dates and values and listing telling you how many days are in the month.  Create a chart like you usually would of line or whatever.  Setting the 'values' as 'val' in the example and 'Category Groups' as 'dt' in example.
3. When chart is created click the horizontal grid till there is a dotted rectangle ONLY around that portion (the x axis).  Click 'Horizontal Chart properties'.
4. Change axis type to be 'Scalar' radio button.  Select as follows:

   a. Change Minimum to [Min(dt)]
   b. Change Maximum to [Max(dt)]
   c. Change Interval to be this expression:

   ```
   =(Fields!DaysInMonth.Value - 1)
   ```

   d. Change Interval type to be 'Days' instead
5. Run your report and it should be grouping by days, but using the data you found to be the count of days in a month dynamically at run time.  Since you are subtracting one from this number it should show the grouping for the first day but then the last day each time.  If you find this not to be true I would alter the expression slightly as when I tested it, it worked for the duration I gave.

If this fails you could set a label to be the last day of the month obtained from a sql statement and have that be your 'label' for a category group possibly as well.